# Best practice of retrieving params and queryParams in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I'm trying to understand the way of creating a route, with some information in it's URL parameters.

This is my route (app.routes.ts):

```
{path: 'results/:id', component: MyResultsComponent},
```

This is how I navigate to the route :

```
goToResultsPage(query: string) {
this.router.navigate(['results', query], { queryParams: { pageSize: 20 } });}
```

As you can see, I've also a query parameter. I was wondering, what is the best and cleanest way to retrieve this in my `MyResultsComponent`. Right now I've kind of a nested `subscribe` structure:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route
      .params
      .subscribe(params => {
        this.query = params['id'];
        this.route
          .queryParams
          .subscribe(queryParams => {
            this.offset = queryParams['pageSize'];
            #find entries this.entryService.findEntries(this.query, this.pageSize);
      });
    });
  }
```

Afterwards, I want to pass this parameters to my `EntryService`, which returns the found entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using a forkJoin?

ForkJoin allows you to join two observables and wait for the response of both them. You can see the documentation [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md) and read more about it [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html).

As for your code it would look something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    Observable.forkJoin(this.route.params, this.route.queryParams).subscribe(bothParams => {
        // bothParams is an array, on the first index we have the router.params 
        // on the second index we have the queryParams
        this.query = bothParams[0].query;
        this.pageSize = bothParams[0].pageSize;
        this.entryService.findEntries(this.query, this.pageSize);
    });
  }
```

You might need to add imports:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
```

Comment: In case anyone else experiences the `subscribe` not firing, it's because all the observables need to complete beforehand, they can't be left dangling. You'll need to use `.take(1)` or `.first()` before your forkJoin subscribe will fire.

Comment: @ScottByers but then surely you can't navigate to another page and reuse this route?

Comment: Correct; but it's the only way to make `forkJoin` complete. You could easily write another subscribe on the same stream to keep responding to changes and do the full forkJoin call again. Observables like these are cold until subscribed so you can do it multiple times.

Answer (score 22):

The Observable.combineLatest is a solution in this situation, isn't it?

```
Observable
  .combineLatest(
    this.route.params,
    this.route.queryParams,
    (params: any, queryParams: any) => {
      return {
        id: +params.id,
        pageSize: queryParams.pageSize ? +queryParams.pageSize: null
      }
    })
  .subscribe(bothParams => {
    this.id = bothParams.id;
    this.pageSize = bothParams.pageSize;
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing... Works perfect ! for the routeParam and queryParams scenario.

Comment: It's fire twice from aaa/:bbb?ccc=10 to 'aaa/:bb'

Answer (score 9):

I guess if you need to access both at the same time the snapshot is a better option.

Not tested (just from the top of my head)

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route
      .params
      .subscribe(params => {
        this.query = params['id'];
        this.offset = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['pageSize'];
        # find entries this.entryService.findEntries(this.query, this.pageSize);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Tested it and works for me. This is the simplest solution among the other answers

Comment: This will fail when params remains the same and queryParam changes

Answer (score 2):

I've faced this dilemma recently and the best solution fitting my needs I've found is to use `Observable.merge`.

Using snapshot is not good if you want to watch changes from params queryParams within the same component (i.e search with filters).

`Observable.forkJoin` has the limitation that both observables must be triggered in order to work, so if you have a scenario where there might be changes in params or in queryParams, but not necessarily in both, forkJoin wouldn't hep you.

`Observable.merge` on the other hand is triggered with either one of them being triggered. Of course, this also has some drawbacks since you might have two callbacks being called one after the other (at the beginning with params and queryParams).

Here is an example:

```
Observable.merge(
  this.route.params.map(params => this.handleParams(params)),
  this.route.queryParams.map(queryParams => this.handleQueryParams(queryParams))
)
.subscribe(
  () => this.onParamsOrQueryParamsChange()
);
```

Comment: What about Observable.combineLatest? See my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.route.queryParams
    .subscribe((params: Params) => {
      console.log('PARAMS',params);
      }
    });
},0);
```

Answer (score 0):

2023

But it can still be a struggle for some.

What I found is that actually in your app.component do the folowing

```
this._router.events.pipe(startWith(this._router)).subscribe((event) => {
    let queryparams;
    let url; 
    if (event instanceof ActivationEnd) {
        queryparams = event.snapshot.queryparams;
    }
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        SomeService.routevent.next({url:event.url,queryparams:queryparams});
    }
});
```

Create a service  and give it a BehaviourSubject routevent. Then whatever component or place you need the latest url or queryparams